# Table view - empty background space while delete items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

While I delete a row from tableview it renders content in a strange way with empty space below and above - see video record and bug image:
[deformed table view after call deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44dXy.jpg)

Probably, it may be caused by constraints changes (top view expanding / collapsing), or incorrect delete operations.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffSetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    switch true {

    case contentOffSetY < 0 && searchViewIsHidden && !topMainViewIsHidden:
        changeSearchVisibility(false)

    case contentOffSetY > 0 && !searchViewIsHidden && !topMainViewIsHidden:
        changeSearchVisibility(true)

    case contentOffSetY > maxHeaderHeight && searchViewIsHidden && !topMainViewIsHidden:
        transformTopView(toBig: false)

    case self.contentOffSetY <= 0 && searchViewIsHidden && topMainViewIsHidden:
        transformTopView(toBig: true)

    default:
        break
    }
}

// Indexes of items that should be changed from Realm Observer    
func updateTableView(_ deletions: [Int], 
    _ insertions: [Int], _ modifications: [Int]) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .none)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                     with: .none)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: What if you comment the whole `scrollViewDidScroll` method? Does the problem persist?

Comment: Do you have any other `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods in your class?

Comment: Can you mark on the screenshot where does your `UITableView` end? It's not clear if search header is a part of the table (cell) or it is on top of it vertically or it is behind `UITableView` (different z-index of some sort).

Comment: It'd be great if you'll also provide methods `changeSearchVisibility` and `transformTopView`.

Comment: @AndreiKonstantinov here is the screen record, I forgot to add it to initial question
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XpFlLtLYDYBdd54OuBa6ouPrs_WEhaRS)

`var searchViewIsHidden: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            switch searchViewIsHidden {
            case true:
                serachHeaderHeightConstraint.constant = minHeaderHeight // CGFfloat = 0
            case false:
                serachHeaderHeightConstraint.constant = maxHeaderHeight // CGFloat = 47
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Have you tried suggestion from first comment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a perfect solution but you could try redrawing the entire tableview after deleting a row. With reloadData()

Let me know if this works for you.